# How to right click to select text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to right click on a textarea to select the text and bring up the options dialogue at the same time?

I want to eliminate the additional click of left clicking to select all the text and then right clicking to select 'copy' in

```
<textarea onclick="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">
example text
</textarea>
```

Comment: Why don't you offer a `copyAll` option in a context menu that selects all the text and copies to the clipboard after the user clicks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use oncontextmenu instead of onclick..

Answer (score 1):

**oncontextmenu** is the event you are looking for.

```
<textarea oncontextmenu="this.focus();this.select()" readonly="readonly">
example text
</textarea>
```

for reference http://jsfiddle.net/EyNWz/

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the oncontextmenu event as in this example:

```
<div oncontextmenu="this.focus();this.select();return false;" readonly="readonly">
    example text
</div>
```

Use "return false" if you don't want the standard context menu to pop up, just in case you changed your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different way to implement the RIGHT CLICK by Jquery.

event.which == 3 means right click.

```
$('textarea').mousedown(function(event) {
if(event.which == 3){
    var THIS = $(this);
    THIS.focus();
    THIS.select();
  }
});
```